# Knight Distance

Tags: code-golf, integer, graph-theory, chess

In Chess, a Knight on grid \$(x, y)\$ may move to \$(x-2, y-1)\$, \$(x-2, y+1)\$, \$(x-1, y-2)\$, \$(x-1, y+2)\$, \$(x+1, y-2)\$, \$(x+1, y+2)\$, \$(x+2, y-1)\$ or \$(x+2, y+1)\$ in one step. Imagine an infinite chessboard with only a Knight on \$(0, 0)\$:

> How many steps is required for moving a Knight from \$(0, 0)\$ to \$(t_x, t_y)\$?

### Inputs

Two integers: \$t_x\$, \$t_y\$;

\$-100 < t_x < 100\$, \$-100 < t_y < 100\$

### Output

Minimal steps needed to move a Knight from \$(0, 0)\$ to \$(t_x, t_y)\$

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Testcases

```
  x    y -> out
  0,   0 ->  0
  0,   1 ->  3
  0,   2 ->  2
  1,   1 ->  2
  1,   2 ->  1
  3,   3 ->  2
  4,   0 ->  2
 42,  22 -> 22
 84,  73 -> 53
 45,  66 -> 37
 99,  99 -> 66
-45, -91 -> 46
-81,   1 -> 42
 11,  -2 ->  7
```

```js
document.write('<div>');[..."EFEDEDCDCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCDCDEDEFE;FEDEDCDCBCBABABABABABABABABABABABCBCDCDEDEF;EDEDCDCBCBABABABABABABABABABABABABCBCDCDEDE;DEDCDCBCBABA9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9ABABCBCDCDED;EDCDCBCBABA9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9ABABCBCDCDE;DCDCBCBABA9A9898989898989898989A9ABABCBCDCD;CDCBCBABA9A989898989898989898989A9ABABCBCDC;DCBCBABA9A98987878787878787878989A9ABABCBCD;CBCBABA9A9898787878787878787878989A9ABABCBC;BCBABA9A989878767676767676767878989A9ABABCB;CBABA9A98987876767676767676767878989A9ABABC;BABA9A9898787676565656565656767878989A9ABAB;CBA9A989878767656565656565656767878989A9ABC;BABA98987876765654545454545656767878989ABAB;CBA9A987876765654545454545456567678789A9ABC;BABA98987676565454343434345456567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565454343434343454565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676545434323232343454567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565434323232323434565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676545432341214323454567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565434321232123434565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676545432323032323454567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565434321232123434565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676545432341214323454567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565434323232323434565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676545434323232343454567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876565454343434343454565678789A9ABC;BABA98987676565454343434345456567678989ABAB;CBA9A987876765654545454545456567678789A9ABC;BABA98987876765654545454545656767878989ABAB;CBA9A989878767656565656565656767878989A9ABC;BABA9A9898787676565656565656767878989A9ABAB;CBABA9A98987876767676767676767878989A9ABABC;BCBABA9A989878767676767676767878989A9ABABCB;CBCBABA9A9898787878787878787878989A9ABABCBC;DCBCBABA9A98987878787878787878989A9ABABCBCD;CDCBCBABA9A989898989898989898989A9ABABCBCDC;DCDCBCBABA9A9898989898989898989A9ABABCBCDCD;EDCDCBCBABA9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9ABABCBCDCDE;DEDCDCBCBABA9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9A9ABABCBCDCDED;EDEDCDCBCBABABABABABABABABABABABABCBCDCDEDE;FEDEDCDCBCBABABABABABABABABABABABCBCDCDEDEF;EFEDEDCDCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCDCDEDEFE"].forEach(c=>document.write(c==';'?'<br>':`<span class="d-${c}">${c}</span>`));
document.write('<style>body{line-height:16px;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}span{display:inline-block;width:16px;font-size:16px;text-align:center;}div{white-space:pre;}');[...'0123456789ABCDEF'].map((c,i)=>document.write(`.d-${c}{background:hsl(${60-4*i},80%,${65-2*i}%)}`));
```

### Related OEIS

Here are some OEIS for further reading

- [A018837](https://oeis.org/A018837): Number of steps for knight to reach \$(n,0)\$ on infinite chessboard.
- [A018838](https://oeis.org/A018838): Number of steps for knight to reach \$(n,n)\$ on infinite chessboard.
- [A065775](https://oeis.org/A065775): Array \$T\$ read by diagonals: \$T(i,j)=\$ least number of knight's moves on a chessboard (infinite in all directions) needed to move from \$(0,0)\$ to \$(i,j)\$.
- [A183041](https://oeis.org/A183041): Least number of knight's moves from \$(0,0)\$ to \$(n,1)\$ on infinite chessboard.

Comment: You may take a reference of the formula given in https://oeis.org/A065775

Comment: Can I take input as a complex number `x+yi`?

Comment: @lynn i think it is acceptable.

Comment: @user202729 updated the code snippet to show the result.

Comment: A very fine map.

Answer (score 12):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 64 bytes

Using the built-in [`KnightTourGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KnightTourGraph.html).

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mathe172](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70782/mathe172).

```
GraphDistance[KnightTourGraph@@({x,y}=Abs@{##}+4),y+2,(x-2)y-2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCoMwFEV/5UFAFBPQaFszWFIodOjSoZs4pKI1g7ZoCork21NjQ6dz7z2P1wnV1p1QshKmgdxcBvFuz3JUoq/q4trLZ6vur8@w7Zz7y4RnnZ8eI18Q0mEa4Dmk2J8IDWZCS8/cBtmrwkogR2gKhMoSPOCcw7JEGCKNwTJ2pJax67HrCYbEMnX3KV3FZrJ1OvzcDsN@bxNjGBizidiRsO0Xyf5f10Co1uYL)

[image: ArrayPlot@Array[GraphDistance[KnightTourGraph@@({x,y}=Abs@{##}+5),2y+3,(x-2)y-2]&,{65,65},-32]]

Comment: Mathematica builtins strike again

Comment: Slightly shorter: `GraphDistance[KnightTourGraph@@({x,y}=Abs@{##}+5),2y+3,(x-2)y-2]&`

Comment: What's with this language? How come all these built-ins are preloaded? Does trying to complete a phrase with tab takes ages?

Comment: @OganM Mathematica doesn't support auto completion in its command line interface. The auto completion in the notebook interface looks like [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Files/UsingTheInputAssistant.en/2.gif).

Comment: @OganM Maybe the developers use a Trie (data structure), or just binary search on the list of sorted built-ins. Yes, why linear search? | Note that Mathematica is a non-free closed-source language, so no one know how the predictor actually works. | Real programmers don't need auto-complete. :P

Comment: @aleph Actually the long builtin names make this a bit uncompetitive... as usual.

Comment: Wow, it just like a semi-_transparent_ image!

Comment: Just when you think Mathematica doesn't have enough builtins...

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> <s>75</s> 72 bytes

Inspired by the formula given for [A065775](https://oeis.org/A065775). Slow as hell for (not so) long distances.

```javascript
f=(x,y,z=x|y)=>z<0?f(-y,x):z>1?1+Math.min(f(x-1,y-2),f(x-2,y-1)):z*3^x&y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7hCoIwEAfw7z3FPsVWN/U2IYjUJ@gVArEsw1ykxCa9u12gIMxgYwe/@9/tnr/ztnhVz0425nwZyoQOt@CgT@zHiSTtD1FWcunAin2fYobbY97dgkfV8JJbieCkEvArFZUoqGujT3bthsI0rakvQW2u1MpYBHSFYGFI72pJcVS9qGpU5SnOsss6ZdFTTar/ZuPZnz2NFTA1TlaeIu2V097d8AU)

### How?

We define **z** as the bitwise OR between **x** and **y**.

#### Step #1

We first ensure that we are located in a specific quadrant by forcing both **x** and **y** to be non-negative. As long as **z < 0** (which means that either **x** or **y** is negative), we process the recursive call **f(-y, x)**:

```
(+1, -2) --> (+2, +1)
(-1, +2) --> (-2, -1) --> (+1, -2) --> (+2, +1)
(-1, -2) --> (+2, -1) --> (+1, +2)
```

#### Step #2

While we have **z > 1** (which means that either **x** or **y** is greater than **1**), we recursively try the two moves that bring us closer to **(0, 0)**: **f(x-1, y-2)** and **f(x-2, y-1)**. We eventually keep the shortest path.

#### Step #3

When **z** is less than or equal to **1**, we're left with 3 possibilities which are processed with `z*3^x&y` (we could use `z*3-x*y` instead):

- **x & y == 1** implies **x | y == 1** and means that **x = y = 1**. We need two more moves to reach **(0, 0)**:

  [image: 2 moves]
- **x & y == 0** and **x | y == 1** means that we have either **x = 1** / **y = 0** or **x = 0** / **y = 1**. We need three more moves to reach **(0, 0)**:

  [image: 3 moves]
- **x & y == 0** and **x | y == 0** means that we already have **x = y = 0**.

*<sub>Graphics borrowed from [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor)</sub>*

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 90 bytes

Thanks tsh for -11 bytes!

`def f(x,y):x=abs(x);y=abs(y);s=x+y;return(.9+max(x/4,y/4,s/6)-s/2+(s==1or x==y==2))//1*2+s`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBBbsMgELzziq16YQsOsZ1Wii0e49Ym5RCIwKnY1ztgmlMOuxpmpJlZbrT@etdv27wYMDxJwiHp6TvyhCPtgHCMOgkaw7Leg@OHs7hOiSd1kpQnqi9souoEj1q3PkDSmrTuEJVqPzoRd@tLtYZ3@PHzAib4Kxgb4gph@bPResfgJZeBNZCTs@9Qw6GvXI14kicG/yj4u5s5L/32VUJFe/hE1clKCJKpIUlNQtGh6rHJzyxjrppFxpzuj0dmyiFgs@PkLgtvnHQ4MCg0vdKlU/28N/289BasWwuWVZFVwO0B)

(inline code formatting to avoid readers having to scroll. Sorry, but I have to golf my program)

Very very efficient.

---

#### How could I come up with this!?

**1. Parity**

Assumes that the whole board is colored in the checkerboard pattern (that is, cells with `x+y` odd and `x+y` even are colored with different colors).

Note that each step must jump between two differently-colored cell. Therefore:

- The parity of the number of steps must be equal to the parity of `x+y`.

**2. Approximation**

Assumes the knight starts from coordinate `(0,0)`, and have moved `n` steps, and is currently at `(x,y)`.
For simplicity, assumes `x ≥ 0`, `y ≥ 0`.
We can conclude:

- Since each step `x` increases by at most `2`, `x ≤ 2×n`. Similarly, `y ≤ 2×n`.
- Since each step `x+y` increases by at most `3`, `x+y ≤ 3×n`.

Therefore, `n ≥ l(x,y)` where `l(x,y) = max(max(x,y)/2, (x+y)/3`. (note that we don't need to include `-x` or `x-y` in the formula because by assumption, `x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 0`, so `x+y ≥ max(x-y,y-x,-x-y)` and `x ≥ -x`, `y ≥ -y`)

It turns out that `a(x,y) = round(0.4 + l(x,y))` is a good approximation to `n`.

- Assume `a(x,y)` is an approximation with error less than `1`, the correct value is given by

  ```python
  f(x,y) = round((a(x,y) - (x+y)) / 2) * 2 + (x+y)
  ```

  (round under subtracting `x+y` and dividing by 2)

**3. Special cases that fails the formula**

Assume `x ≥ 0` and `y ≥ 0`. There are 2 special cases where the algorithm fails:

- `x == 1 and y == 0` or `x == 0 and y == 1`: The algorithm incorrectly returns `1` while the correct answer is `3`.
- `x == y == 2`: The algorithm incorrectly returns `2` while the correct answer is `4`.

So, just special-case those. Add the result by `2` if the value of `x` and `y` are one of those.

Comment: @tsh But that is true for `x==y==0` too.

Comment: Why `max(x+y,x-y,y-x)`?

Comment: @tsh: No, see: x = -5, y = 5. x+y = 0, abs(x-y) = 10 and therefore x+y < abs(x-y)

Comment: @Nova "Assume `x ≥ 0` and `y ≥ 0`".

Comment: the link code doesnt print anything

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda z,a={0}:1-({z}<=a)and-~f(z,{k+1j**i*(2-i/4*4+1j)for k in a for i in range(8)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc/LcoMgFAbgPU9xdoCVNiLxkil9km5ooymNQaNOp9Wxr24PpEk2DN/8cC7dz/jROrmutW7M6W1vYIqNnjfLLhFsnpZnbbhxe/Fbsymejw/JZxTZiElhn1SkkLxueziCdWDAX62/9sYdKlbwha@DppQCbGLAA8QLnuSfSWB6pQyUyOSe3nhJE2Tqmd5Sda@MVBIpw2OJLHyah8dbbKS2yCzzTHMCZYksS88sI8Knogx9FbK4j6GwVOIpLmPkuBMhft3GuspvPDwOXWNHRl8d5Tscq4vhDDrk18h/pdxnvXUj1Oy9PXVN9c2i6ss0rOOcg9ZYbWRnTtY/)

Takes input as a complex number `z = complex(tx, ty)`.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, <s>86</s> 54 bytes

Based on @user202729's older solution

```
Input :abs(X->C:abs(Y->D:C+Ans
Ans+2int(.9+(S=1 or C=2 and D=2)-.5Ans+max({C/4,D/4,Ans/6
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 29 bytes

```
`JEQ2J-htZjht_h@Z^2&sG=~}@Gg*
```

Input is a complex number with integer real and imaginary parts.

The code is very inefficient. Its memory requirements increase exponentially with the output. It times out in TIO for the test cases with output exceeding 7.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HLNdDISzejJCoroyQ@wyEqzkit2N22rtbBPV3r/39DQ12jLAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
1,-pḤµ;UÆị
¢ṗS€;0i
0ç1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//MSwtcOG4pMK1O1XDhuG7iwrCouG5l1Pigqw7MGkKMMOnMSP///8wKzFq)

Very slow; times out on TIO for outputs over 6. Takes a complex number as input.

#### Explanation

The code uses complex numbers because it was shorter in an intermediate step and it also seems a lot faster; you could also use pairs by removing `Æi` and replacing `0` with `0,0` on the second line.

```
1,-pḤµ;UÆị    Helper link. No arguments.
1,-             Get the pair [1,-1].
    Ḥ           Double each to get [2,-2].
   p            Cartesian product: get [[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2]].
     µ          Start a new chain with the list of pairs as argument.
       U        Reverse each pair.
      ;         Append the reversed pairs to the list.
        Æi      Convert each pair [real,imag] to a complex number.

¢ṗS€;0i    Helper link. Arguments: iterations, target
¢            Call the previous link to get knight moves as complex numbers.
 ṗ           Get the iterations-th Cartesian power of the list. This will
             yield 8^n tuples containing move sequences.
  S€         Sum each move sequence to get the resulting square.
    ;0       Add the starting square, since the zeroth iteration results
             in no move sequences.
      i      Find the target squares (1-based) index in the results, or 0.

0ç1#    Main link. Argument: target
0         Starting from 0,
   #      find the
  1       first number of iterations where
 ç        calling the previous link results in a nonzero result.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>79</s> 72 bytes

```
p l|elem(0,0)l=0|r<-[-2..2]=1+p[(x+i,y+j)|(x,y)<-l,i<-r,j<-r,(i*j)^2==4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsMgFEXRrTjU@hU1GeoSugJJiwOhWg1iWkjAvVvr5HAHj/dyx9un1HtBqfnkMxYgSDKiVc0sU5yrzUhaLD5pgItG0vAJF9EsQdCsQvyDwy2ShzJm3Xp2YUcGZVfuT4RLDfuHF16@1RNk5zsM5VQN5Ww5e4FluM6NlMAU2VD/AQ)

Takes the input as [a singleton list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/34531) of pairs of numbers.

A simple brute force. Needs a lot of time and memory for results > 8. Starting with a single element list of coordinates (the input), repeatedly add all positions that can be reached for every element until `(0,0)` is in this list. Keep track of the recursion level and return it as the result.

Edit: -7 bytes thanks to @Lynn.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsMgFEXRrTjU@hU1GeoSugJJiwOhWg1iWkjAvVvr5HAHj/dyx9un1HtBrvnkMxYgiDOiVc0sU5yrzUhaLD5pgItG0vAJF9HMQdCsQvyDwy2ShzJm3Xp2YUcGZVfuT4RLDfuHF16@1RNk5zsM5VQN5Ww5e4FluM6NlMAU2VD/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> 78 bytes

```
f=(x,y)=>y<0?f(x,-y):x<y?f(y,x):x+y<3?4-x-y&3:x-3|y-1?x-4|y-3?f(x-2,y-1)+1:3:2
```

Edit: Saved 12 bytes thanks to @supercat pointing out that `x<0` implies either `y<0` or `x<y`. Explanation: This is a recursive solution. The first two conditions just ensure the right quadrant for the other conditions. The third condition generates the answer for coordinates near the origin, while the last two conditions deal with the other two special cases (1 byte shorter than testing both moves):

```
0
32
2++
+2++
+++3+
++++++
(etc.)
```

All squares marked `+` can be determined by moving directly towards the origin and then recursing.

Comment: Do you need the `x<0` test?  Given e.g. -3,6, the `x<y` test would turn that into 6,-3, which the `y<0` test would turn into 6,3, which the `x<y` test would turn into 3,6.

Comment: @supercat Indeed, as Python would say, `x>=y>=0`...

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>148</s> <s>146</s> 140 bytes

```
fun s(x:Int,y:Int):Int=if(y<0)s(x,-y)else
if(x<y)s(y,x)else if(x+y<3)4-x-y and 3
else if(x!=3||y!=1)if(x!=4||y!=3)s(x-2,y-1)+1
else 3 else 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVbbbts4EH3XV0yDYmvV8kWSYyfeuEbRbdFgLwHavAV5kG3a1kYXl6QSC02@PXuGlGzFSdsNEJnDuXLmzJA3uU7i7LH3lj5IEWmxoGUuaZ4vBK3yZEnzdZQkIluJsbPWeqPGvR4zmddVOprfiC1EwO/O87T3rRBKx3mmev4wPB6NnD@zeLXW9EcM2WwuHOc8ow9roZRHEVXMPKOVjBfU2npUupRGJaX5rSCdY6sTYLPju169bldrn/eD/bpt1@3Gfru537DTruxQnMG5IKXFpkvnabSKQUUZ9pdxFmuB0yPUWR7JBd3Feg3ppHwSeKvvUd8dOw7h73N@h@iz0hhUFCuS4lsRyyqpOFScrfbqS5mnlQFzVo3z69KdcpI2hVaOc3mXIxYtVkKqMVn@747T8ft9OgOND5Ye1Rul3XAuCg0DjvM3TpFGSRVPJsQCocCVSe@v4ug6X4pEKHu0HSAQFEo8j5TlbJlZUucd5XBIBCv4ME39mvQNGdZkYMgApL/n7kjL9UGGTIY77mBvGeQAJaTACAcgT5g7MsLHcDQ4BjkcMhmOHDo9BXl6yuRw6HSY2zk1fgcgT/ZhDGDKZ7Jjwxg5zheRmK64@Hj@1XE@C4nE4V/lqTB7prLLQuq1kCh3tECJbcre9/2Tk3A0pn@KdAZmvqzqwBo3NvVIN3Tma2plHrKfvwi9bsPcyf82l/3K3BD9eTym91Ki4S5N7DQraRFHqzyLEgDushV7/7qTRERKU7Zza529UQZGir1EzUZp7XyivTA8YFGKuZkK7iEGa@hVyGN3VXj@Sdgf@GP66@fODwxknv/jYzv@oI8TaiD3be9xWWSkWtvxeaa9kr8ufybxslWe9V1wvE7pikQJB1vbsxJbpbc1O8Q77fIsdAedbQcDIVsA3jvOq0l4f1@@mviupQaGCtkmJhgPobZvpUMyP8Gj0@vRx@0GhpCcW3Q7skWF4nEBYNEy3mLfJkGZtLLCtyJayCjTXbqEzJTmmFwzFl4VPHLQkFzPNLphSEI@sjkvMh0nFicv2jfmWP6pV7ae5frQwzyXXN2kZA0bccRlX@USAzNFo5h@WTMyeIigDhDs8ycMuNKtK0yF4NqjK7S0z788ia55UF/xYA/2W6wUTKdG6TlnalgvcqbTcApOWDk4kDBIQCsBDMRooNL8uuZLE@5mGDlfYs7FPEVXkY5vhceZRcE1bXIV806XPsUSYN1EUlsd4BXdOeekYIznJtf7qn0RupAZb1ppKVSRaMZ/vKQWz/K@a5rBBoehVbpVMBc8bu5ihSggu@W4VMoXtYQ55L/0SOHCwiSAYNq1Sl/FPAdSObyfR2bF9@E1IqtAjksU4ZWN8OBx@0J0W/oNaWME8P0ZZ08cMTjipdVBP/Ep@tzGASZBF@l8Efq7dC1NsvVaCkF4wvAkWu5NRzNg3XNJFTMto3lVkFmOS9zMjIHp2lmsOU7bwQx8hLASWgHJuKyszt1aZFZxf5j@gSyQZcS2VgUc38jyibrNfOimVmC1qgSwcLDTIkx145Td@d1fVaPNcAltPZpD6Udwyd5oTB/4KCsCPYFZOb/BaLGZArDTXIqDor@aQO3@HmpY@a696Wx31GYHTbOcGEGLnNfriF8dtYbaiHmMtwk/JRgIEOMRg2FSSN6p6sazq9KIGndGVQqcUR4mhjZJoWodPO/shbILf7ALv0pX3V/1SxPDudZ@AmRUxYLGFCjkmCvfoXVhLgtrMXypE4zWzoDfMBDUWTbqgcNDi59ZtJCYK9JMqDSKs1YkV6q6ss@@aonkvHPpe@XMaJiXGZu7rXKraAIMQeFi2aqiq0mef/zq85o7AELoes8lkZ2gIekbyeCZpG8k/YYkIBC@JDkw3ps2@VEXmP9nwvzAG8HMcdiUx0NuOIT50TN5fvLx/3DYkK9ffh7efc80zDuQWU9OiQ3GxXMHYX3@5nn4qG49BT@hDcxjDA8OXCobITFxU74wGAMbFE8ftDO/5FoszXPO1I6Ly165mBW6J3i1sMxVH1eYWfjXFsjGZJK1jq5ef68kHjyq1v71w/XkqF2dgujo9Xdr8IHqFU0m1mBw/XDEJh/MmM2lYxYMQOfxPw)

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need the `:Int` to specify return type.

Comment: Recursive functions do require return type as the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out the type.

Comment: Oh, I missed the recursive calls. Whoops